# Azure error: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\`'

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm trying to upload a VHD file to the Azure Storage (classic). In cmd, I'm executing this command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>azure vm image create boot2dockerhyperv ` --blob-url https://URL.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/boot2dockerhyperv.vhd ` --os Linux "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\boot2dockerhyperv.vhd"`
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
info:    Executing command vm image create
error:   ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\`'
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\USERNAME\.azure\azure.err
```

This is the content of `azure.err`

```
2016-11-17T09:25:34.903Z:
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\`']
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\`' }
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\`'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
at uploadPageBlobFromBlobService (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\iaas\upload\pageBlob.js:278:17)
at Object.uploadPageBlob (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\iaas\upload\pageBlob.js:221:3)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\iaas\upload\uploadVMImage.js:83:16
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\commands\asm\iaas\upload\uploadVMImage.js:65:5
at callbacks.(anonymous function) (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\callbackAggregator.js:81:30)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\node_modules\azure-asm-storage\lib\storageManagementClient.js:1419:14
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\logging.js:339:7
at handleRedirect (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\lib\util\utils.js:564:9)
```

When executed in PowerShell, I get a different error

```
info:    Executing command vm image create
info:    VHD size : 20 GB
info:    Uploading 59392.5 KB
error:   body.outputStream.on is not a function
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\USERNAME\.azure\azure.err
```

**UPDATE:**

The file seem to appear in the Azure portal even with the error but I'm freaking out because it's showing that the size is 19.53GiB

[image]

Comment: did u try it from a normal folder like D:\VHDimage or something like that. maybe powershell does not have permissions to the system32 folder.

Comment: @Aravind I moved the file to `D:\boot2dockerhyperv` but I get the same PowerShell error. However, when I checked the portal I can see the file. But why is it freaking 19.53GB? Please see update :)

Comment: I am not sure of the powershell error if u had followed the right steps. as far as the VHD file size it must be same as the size ( the one you created using sysprep) that you have it your machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json

Comment: Any updates, have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> error:   body.outputStream.on is not a function
>   error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\USERNAME.azure\azure.err

According to your description, I could reproduce this error on my side. And I found a related issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/2230

As mentioned in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-classic-create-upload-vhd):

> Azure does not support uploading dynamic VHDs, so you need to convert such disks to static VHDs before uploading. You can use tools such as [Azure VHD Utilities for GO](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-vhd-utils) to convert dynamic disks during the process of uploading to Azure.

Also, I have tried to upload my vhd to blob storage as follows:

[image]

[image]

Please try to follow the document I mentioned and also check the link provided by Aravind.